# cocoapodsでPodfileに書かれていないのがインストールされる

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

cocoapodsでPodfileに書かれていないのがインストールされます。
これの解決方法をご存知の方は教えていただければ幸いです。

一応勝手にインストールされるライブラリー名はGHODictionary (1.0.7)でございます。

過去に一回ぐらい入れた記憶もあります。
ただ、今はPodfileには書いていません。

コメントありがとうございます。中身は以下の通りです。

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2'
pod 'Alamofire-SwiftyJSON', :git => "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.git"
pod 'Starscream', '~> 0.9'
pod 'MPMessagePack', '~> 1.1'
```

Comment: 他のPodの依存関係になってるのではないでしょうか。今の情報だけではわからないので、Podfileの中身を全部載せてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。本文に追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPMessagePackがGHODictionaryに依存しているためです。

MPMessagePackを使うにはGHODictionaryが必要なため、自動的にインストールされます。

https://github.com/gabriel/MPMessagePack/blob/master/MPMessagePack.podspec#L12

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！　因みに、勝手？に追加されたライブラリーもembedする必要があるでしょうか。。今は特にやってないですが動作には問題なかったですが、、